# How to call async Function until condition is true using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have such a problem, I am using API call which returns Fake store data, Everything works fine I am pushing received data into `arr` array, my aim is to call `repeatCall()` function until `arr.length` will  be `arr.length === 100`, Also the problem is, sometimes I want to filter received data based on condition and then push it into `arr` array, What would be the optimal solution in this case?

```js
let arr = [];
async function repeatCall() {
    const req = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`);
    const resp = await req.json();
    arr.push(...resp)
    console.log(arr.length)
}

  repeatCall()
```

Comment: `while (arr.length <= 100) { const req = await …; …; arr.push(...resp.filter(condition)); } return arr;`?

Comment: @bergi I am using promises so I have this error, `await is only valid in async functions and the top-level bodies of modules`

Comment: But you placed that inside the `async function repeatCall() {`, and the original code didn't cause that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if condition on arr.length it will fetch api till the length is equal to 100.

```
let arr = [];
async function repeatCall() {
    const req = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`);
    const resp = await req.json();
    arr.push(...resp)
    console.log(arr.length)
    if(arr.length < 100){
              repeatCall();
    }
}
```

As for filtering the data before pushing it to array.

```
let arr = [];
    async function repeatCall() {
        const req = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`);
        const resp = await req.json();
        resp.foreach(item => {
           if(condition){
              arr.push(item);
           }   
           else{
              console.log("don't push")             
           }    
        })
       
        if(arr.length < 100){
                  repeatCall();
        }
        console.log(arr.length)
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the `repeatCall()` result, or otherwise it'll be impossible to properly handle errors